# Using Pydantic parent attribute to validate child?

Tags: python, pydantic

Is it possible to use a containing object's attribute during the validation of a child object in a pydantic model?

Given the json data:

```json
# example.json

{
    "multiplier": 5,
    "field_1": {
        "value": 1
    },
    "field_2": {
        "value": 2
    }
}
```

and the corresponding Pydantic model:

```py
# example.py

from pydantic import BaseModel, validator

class Item(BaseModel):
    value: int

class Container(BaseModel):
    multiplier: int
    field_1: Item
    field_2: Item
```

is it possible to use the `Container` object's `multiplier` attribute during validation of the `Item` values? For instance, I'd like to do something like this to `Item` at runtime:

```py
class Item(BaseModel):
    value: int

    @validator("value")
    @classmethod
    def validate_value(cls, value):
        return value # * multiplier  # <--- can I get access to Container's multiplier here?
```

but I cannot determine if it possible to get access to the `Container.multiplier` value in a case like this?

In my actual use case, the nesting is much, much deeper and so I would prefer not have the validator up at the `Container` level as access becomes fairly complicated, but I also do not want to duplicate the `multiplier` value down at the Item level? Is there any way to pass parameters up and down the object hierarchy within a model of this sort?

Comment: I am not sure this is a good use of Pydantic. The entire model validation concept is pretty much stateless by design and you do not only want to introduce state here, but state that requires a link from _any_ possible model instance to a hypothetical parent instance. Something like this _could_ be cooked up of course, but I would probably advise against it. Just out of curiosity, what would be the real-life use case for something like this?

Comment: Thanks @Daniil Fajnberg. My specific use-case is actually a scenario that has to do with unit conversion. My source json file is full of various values, which can come in all sorts of unit types (Btu/hr-ft2-F, W/m2-k, etc..) depending on the specific item in question. I am hoping to be able to convert units when the file is imported. The 'Container' in the example above holds the unit-type as a string, and the Items are specific value items that then need to be converted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest approach is to perform validation on the parent instead of the child:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator

class Item(BaseModel):
    value: int

class Container(BaseModel):
    multiplier: int
    field_1: Item
    field_2: Item


    @validator("field_1", "field_2")
    def validate_value(cls, v, values):
        """Validate each item"""
        m = values["multiplier"]
```

If you want to define the validator on the child, you can create a function and then call the validation function from the parent:

```
class Item(BaseModel):
    value: int

    @classmethod
    def validate_value(cls, v, **kwargs):
        """Validate each item"""
        m = kwargs.get("multiplier")

        if m * v.value < 10:
            raise ValueError

        return v


class Container(BaseModel):
    multiplier: int
    field_1: Item
    field_2: Item

    @validator("field_1", "field_2", pre=False)
    def validate_items(cls, v, values):
        return Item.validate_value(v, **values)
```

Another alternative is to pass the `multiplier` as a [private model attribute](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/models/#automatically-excluded-attributes) to the children, then the children can use the pydantic validation function, but you'll still need to assign dynamically to the children:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field, validator


class Item(BaseModel):
    multiplier: int  # exclude from parent serialization, workaround for validation
    value: int

    @validator("value", pre=False)
    def validate_value(cls, v, values):
        """Validate each item"""
        m = values["multiplier"]

        if m * v < 10:
            raise ValueError

        return v


class Container(BaseModel):
    multiplier: int
    field_1: Item = Field(..., exclude={'multiplier'})
    field_2: Item = Field(..., exclude={'multiplier'})

    @validator("field_1", "field_2", pre=True)
    def validate_items(cls, v, values):
        
        # Construct from a value, another workaround
        if isinstance(v, int):
            return Item(value=v, multiplier=values["multiplier"])
        
        elif isinstance(v, Item):
            return Item(value=v.value, multiplier=values["multiplier"])


if __name__ == '__main__':

    c = Container(
        multiplier=1,
        field_1=11,
        field_2=22
    )
```

Comment: The OP explicitly stated that he would prefer _not_ to perform validation on the top model because of deep nesting. The second approach is not bad though.

Comment: Thank you @Yaakov Bressler, the second method worked great for my case.

Comment: Good luck @EdMay. Do follow up if you run into other issues.

Answer (score 1):

Pydantic 2, combined with Python's `contextvars` library, provides a good and clean solution. Using a Pydantic wrap model validator, you can set a context variable before starting validation of the children, then clean up the context variable after validation. Example:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, field_validator, model_validator
from contextvars import ContextVar

context_multiplier = ContextVar("context_multiplier")


class Item(BaseModel):
    value: int
    @field_validator("value")
    @classmethod
    def validate_value(cls, value):
        multiplier = context_multiplier.get()
        if value % multiplier != 0:
            raise ValueError(f"not a multiple of {multiplier}")
        return value


class Container(BaseModel):
    multiplier: int
    field_1: Item
    field_2: Item
    @model_validator(mode="wrap")
    @classmethod
    def validate_model(cls, v, handler):
        try:
            multiplier = int(v["multiplier"])
        except KeyError:
            raise ValueError("multiplier required")
        token = context_multiplier.set(v["multiplier"])
        try:
            return handler(v)
        finally:
            context_multiplier.reset(token)
```

Validation succeeds with correct inputs:

```py
>>> Container.model_validate(
...     {"multiplier": 3, "field_1": {"value": 9}, "field_2": {"value": 12}}
... )
Container(multiplier=3, field_1=Item(value=9), field_2=Item(value=12))
```

Validation checks the inputs against the multiplier:

```py
>>> Container.model_validate(
...     {"multiplier": 3, "field_1": {"value": 9}, "field_2": {"value": 11}}
... )
pydantic_core._pydantic_core.ValidationError: 1 validation error for Container
field_2.value
  Value error, not a multiple of 3 [type=value_error, input_value=11, input_type=int]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.1.2/v/value_error
```

Using ContextVar means this solution should also work with async code.